# fetching properties of clicked element in ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am fetching JSON result from a controller action which is then passed to the `$scope` object.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ItemList| filter:itemName ">
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <div class="opener" >
        <img style="text-align:center;display: block;margin: 0 auto" 
             ng-src="@Url.Content("{{item.ImagePath}}")"
             width="50" height="50" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
    </div>
  </td>
```

Using a jquery modal popup to display the image when the image thumbnail is clicked.

Script for modal popup

```
<div id="dialog" title="Item Image">
   <img ng-src="@Url.Content("{{item.ImagePath}}")" 
        width="60" height="60" class="img-responsive img-circle" 
        alt="Tile Image" /> //This is not working
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Item Images/2/1556.jpeg")"
        width="700" height="700" class="img-responsive "
        alt="Tile Image" /> //This is working


 $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "Fade",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "Fade",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

 $(document).on("click", ".opener", function () {
       $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

The popup works when the image path is static, but not when i want the clicked image to be opened.

The image path is ~/Item Images/`CreatorID`/`ItemID`.jpeg.
`CreatorID` and `ItemID` are both present in `ItemList`

Can you please let me know what i'm missing.

Comment: You should not use jquery with angularjs. Angular has a built-in service for modals and generally if you want to modifiy dom don't use jquery but custom directives with jqlite to do it.

Comment: what do you see in developer tools for the code line that is not working ? Is the image path correctly displayed ?

Comment: Use the [ng-click directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to add click handlers to content created by the [ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-click directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to add click handlers to content created by the [ng-repeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ItemList| filter:itemName ">
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <div class="opener" >
        <img style="text-align:center;display: block;margin: 0 auto" 
             ng-src="@Url.Content("{{item.ImagePath}}")"
             width="50" height="50" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"
             ng-click="clickAction($event, item)"
        />
    </div>
  </td>
```

JS

```
$scope.clickAction = function(event, item) {
   //Put action code here
});
```

Comment: but how do i send the selected  `item.ImagePath` to the image tag's Url.Content. As i am opening the dialog by `$("#dialog").dialog("open");`